# Why my RO faucet wouldn't stop leaking even after I'd purchased a brand new one?

Tags: plumbing, leak

I have a Whirlpool "UltraEase" RO filtration system (Model number: WHAROS5) underneath my kitchen sink for a while. And it was time to change the pre and post-filters. So I purchased pre and post-filters from Lowes. The filters on this model RO system have a valve on them so I don't have to shut off the water supply when to change out those filters. But ever since I replaced the pre and post-filters. There's a small leak underneath the kitchen sink. Initially, I couldn't find the leak. So I purchased a brand new RO faucet. Even with the new RO faucet and parts, I still get a small leak near the adapter (see picture). I've then added Teflon tape to where the adapter and the blue tube join. But the system is still leaking at where the red arrow points to in the picture. How can I stop this leak?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may have to turn the water off pull the tubing and trim 1/4” off the end if you have already tried pushing the tube in.

To release the tube press in on the ring and the tube usually pulls right out.
If it feels stuck push in on the ring while pushing in on the tubing then pulling out.
Sometimes a divot forms in the tube and if it won’t seat and seal trimming 1/4” usually fixes the problem.

Comment: Is it the best practice to empty the tank and flush the tubes each tome time I replace the RO membrane or the pre/post filters?

Comment: The systems I have installed had auto flush this is very water intensive because after back washing the membranes the system is flushed if you do not auto flush and are doing it manually that is a lot of ware and tear on the fittings are you testing with Meg ohms per centimeter ? Or pressure across the membrane? If doing it by restive you should be able to trust your meter but if by pressure I would want to dump the tank depending on the flush sequence, usually filtered water is used to backwash or the systems I have worked on that is dumped then forward flow no need to dump this way.